# Changing the TOC style of an Article document-class

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

When typesetting an article documentclass, the sections appear as bold in the table of contents, with no leading dots. I would like to change these to non-bold, and insert some leading dots. I tried the following, but it seems to be ignored. Any ideas?

```
% change section headers and page numbers to normal instead of bold font
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{
\normalfont
}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{%
\normalfont
}
% use leader dots with section headers
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

Comment: It's not standard. It seems like you use `tocloft` package for designing the TOC, however you didn't mention it.

Comment: Further to what Stefan said, the tocloft package might be sensitive to other things you have in your preamble.  Could you post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), please?

Comment: @Stefan: the behaviour described by @Hugo is the standard when using the `article` document class: entries of section type are boldfaced and with no leading dots.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{test section}
\subsection{test section}
\section{test section}
\subsection{test section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: output of this code https://pasteboard.co/H0RlZnh.png

Answer (score 2):

The »tocstyle« package from [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) could be an alternative. Note that this package is in *alpha state* and you'll get a corresponding warning.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \bigskip
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Simply including the package does already what you're after. Further customization is done by declaring new ToC styles. For further information run `texdoc tocstyle` on the command line.

As always, the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.