# How to get lines with dots in the table of contents for sections?

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the TOC style of an Article document-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13438/changing-the-toc-style-of-an-article-document-class)

When I use `\tableofcontents`, It uses `...` as a filler between title and page number for subsections, How I can force it to fill space between title of sections and page numbers as well?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had a confusion :- Whether you want dots or you don't. If you don't, this is a solution you can use `tocloft` with `\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} %empty {} for no dots. you can have any symbol inside. For example put {\ensuremath{\ast}} and see what happens.
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}

\section{one}

\end{document}
```

If you want dots even for chapters and parts this will help you.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for sections, if you really want! (It is default in report and book class (So you may not need it).
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
\part{Part one}
\chapter{Chapter one}    
\section{Section one}
\subsection{subsection one}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove the dots you can use,

```
  \renewcommand\@dotsep{1000}
```

This sets the separation of the dots to a high figure and they vanish. (The LaTeX default figure is 4.5). Since the command includes an `\@` you will have to enclose it within `\makeatletter .... \makeatother`.

To add dots in the section for the article class, you need to redefine the `\l@section` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the question was meant the other way round: How to get dots also for sections :-)

Comment: Thanks, But above comment is correct!

Comment: B@Reza: But for sections `dotfill` will work without doing any thing. You are not getting it?

Comment: @Reza The dots for sections come for free:) in the standard classes. What class are you using?

Comment: I am using article

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Not for article class.

Comment: @Reza Please see edit.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thanks:) Had some more coffee and posted a MWE to do this.

Comment: What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do? I noticed that I can't leave them away.