# how to make hard code in table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am using the `pdfpages` package for including a few pages of pdf to my main LaTeX document, therefore I would like to add some lines to the table of content for that pages by myself. I am using the `titletoc` package as well.

I hope something like the following works:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{Preface to 2ed \titlerule i}
\addtocontents{toc}{Preface to 1ed \titlerule ii}
```

for the display

> Preface to 2ed ............................................ i
>
> Preface to 1ed ............................................ ii

where both "Preface" and the page numbers "i/ii" are typed by myself, while the "titlerule" should be consistent with what is being used.

Can someone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The command `includepdf` has one optional argument where you can specify options. I think you can use the option `addtolist`.

Comment: @Marco Daniel: Thanks, but can this option be used for roman page number? I try this but fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intended something like that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface to 2ed}
\includepdf{preface1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface to 1ed}
\includepdf{preface2}
\chapter{Introduction}
...
\end{document}
```

For the dots see: [Changing the TOC style of an Article document-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13438/changing-the-toc-style-of-an-article-document-class)

Comment: Ok. I forgot the roman numerals. I would add a `\frontmatter` and change the displaymode of the pages counter to roman for the whole part preceeding the actual thesis, work or whatever for consistency. (Even withot using the frontmatter function)

Comment: Can you give the details about roman page numbers? thanks.

Comment: By adding \pagenumbering{roman} I did it. Thanks for your method.

Comment: I am quite new to the community too. But i learned right on my first question that, here, it is unusual to say "thanks". Alternatively it is suggested to upvote. (This is no request. If you do not like it, not upvote it. It is a brief instruction on the coumminity code or so)

Comment: Stackexchange allows people without account (like me) to ask question, and such people haven't the privilege of upvoting.